# Unable to get outbound traffic for azure VM with Private IP

Tags: azure, azure-networking

To elaborate more on the title.

I have a jump server(ubuntu) in azure portal which used to connect the azure virtual machines with private ip.After logging into the Jump server , i am connect to the azure vm's with the private IP's

But i am unable to get outbound traffic for the azure vm's with the private IP.

Kindly let me know if i need to allow any outbound traffic for azure VM's private ip

Answer (score 0):

Ingress and Egress from your virtual network is controlled by Network Security Groups. By default, these do allow all outbound traffic, but if they have been adjusted to block traffic, then you will need to amend them to allow http/s out.

Check what NSGs are impacting the VMs (they can be applied both at the VM and the subnet level) and validate if they allow outbound traffic.

Comment: I am using my own azure portal (free account)
The outbound traffic is allowed by default , I have applied the nsg at the interface level without changing any rules.
So the vm(with private ip) need to get outbound traffic as per my knowledge,
and this is ubuntu server.

from this VM unable to ping any website to check if there any outbound traffic allowed.

Comment: Ok, comment still applies, check your NSG's

Comment: there were no change is the NSG, I have allowed all outbound traffic which is default one.

Comment: When you say it is unable to ping, is it resolving the name ok?

Comment: yes i have done the nslookup from the the azure vm(private ip) i am able to resolve the name

mahesh@vm2:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.5.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1029ms

mahesh@vm2:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.5.14
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4009:807::200e

Comment: I am able to resolve the name using nslookup in the azure vm(private ip) ,but unable to ping it.

And also i can see the vnet have default dns which is azure provided

Comment: ,do you we need to add any dns server (by default it is azure provided)

Comment: You do not need to supply dns. Have you actually tried connecting to an external web site? ICMP is blocked in a lot of areas of azure so ping may not work.

Comment: ok but howcome i can ping google.com from public ip azure vm ,it should be same for both the private ip vm and Public ip vm.

Comment: If you want help can you please answer the questions asked. Are you able to access a website using a browser, wget, curl etc? Not ping

Comment: Sam Cogan Thanks for the help !! yes i can that telnet, wget ,curl are working on the azure private vm.
The only doubt i have is ,if the ICMP is blocked how come the azure vm(public ip) can ping.

Comment: If the ICMP blocked how come azure Vm with public up can ping..?